# How to fix Tosca script? Loginfo says Buffer with name 'WaitTime_S' was not found. What could be the issue and how to fix?

Tags: tosca

I am new to Tosca tool. There are some scripts already created earlier. 
While running Template Instance, Error in loginfo says "Buffer with name 'WaitTime_S' was not found" and script failed.

Answer (score 1):

In Tosca a Buffer is a value that has been set at a previous point in time either dynamically or statically.

Most likely your TestCase requires a Buffer to be set in a previous step or manually.

More information on Buffers can be found in the [Tosca documentation](https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=12.0.0&url=articles/buffer_this.htm)

Comment: Most likely the testcase is trying to read a buffer that was set in a previous test case (but not in the one you're running now).  This is common because buffers remain static between test cases unless explicitly cleared.  Since you mention the test case was created earlier, I'm going out on a limb to assume it may also have been created on a -different machine-, and as such it might work on that other person;s machine, and not on yours...  the other machine has the buffer set, and yours doesn't.  The fix would be to add the buffer to yours...  Or, update the script itself to initialize it.

Comment: Hi MartinThe thanks for reply.. yes you are right the machine is different where the script was generated.. now I just changed to wait time value as 1000 and it worked fine. I removed the before fir now..